# How to simulate a "on_mouse_over" on a drop down menu in Java

Tags: selenium, onmouseover, fluentlenium

I'm using FluentLenium.

I'm trying to simulate a `on_mouse_over` in my java tests. I have to check some boxes in a drop down menu, it's an element not visible...

I have to move the mouse over to make visible this element and be able to use the method `click()` from FluentLenium.

How can i "simulate" a `on_mouse_over` in java?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help !

I found the solution :

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.critereFiltrage")).findElement(By.cssSelector("a"))).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.overview")).findElement(By.cssSelector("a"))).click().build().perform();
```

To explain :

- The first moveToElement() => To go on the A-tag to open the DropDown menu
- The second moveToElement() => To go on the first item in the DropDown Menu
- click() => click on the selected item
- build() => To generate a composite action
- perform() => To launch the built action.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the `Actions()` class.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("opens_menu"))).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("hidden_element"))).click().build().perform();
```

Docs are here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html

Comment: Actually I just noticed you're using Fluentlenium, rather that WebDriver. As such I can't guarantee that you have access to the `Actions()` class. If not, please let me know and I'll delete my answer so avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: I tried something like you : 
action.moveToElement((WebElement) ((Actions) driver.findElement(By.id("div.zoneFiltrage"))).moveToElement(find("div.zoneFiltrage").find("ul.critereFiltrage").findFirst("div.overview").findFirst("li").findFirst("a").getElement())).click().build().perform();

I think that my major problem is : I don't have ID for that dropDownMenu ...

When i try to create my test with Selenium IDE 2.0 and export it in JAVA JUNIT4 / WebDriver. I can't run and succeed that test because Selenium IDE probably By-Pass the move_over.

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.id("div.zoneFiltrage")`
That looks more like a css selector - have you tried `driver.findElement(By.css("div.zoneFiltrage"))`?